# table without overlapping but with scrollbar for too-large cell content

Tags: html, css

I want to create a table that fills the screen horizontally but does not grow larger than it. In one table cell I need to put content with arbitrary size that shall be displayed with a horizontal scrollbar if too large.

I tried this:

```
    <table style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%;">
    <tr><td>DONT OVERLAP ME</td><td width=100%>some other content</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2>
        <div style="width:100%; overflow-x:auto;">
CONTENT_WITH_ARBITRARY_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT_THE_TABLE_CELL_SHOULD_DISPLAY_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBARS_BUT_SHOULD_GROW_VERTICALLY_NORMALLY
        </div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>DONT OVERLAP ME</td><td width=100%>some other content</td></tr>
    </table>
```

This works for the scrollbar, but because of "table-layout:fixed" the table loses all ability to resize the table according to available space and displayable content. I need that because the content is fully dynamic and I have no way of knowing how much space a column would need, but I do know which colums should be greedy with the available space (thus the 100% width column).

In other words, it overlaps the "DONT OVERLAP ME" part in the above example.

So I try this:

```
    <table style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%;">
    <tr><td>
    <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr><td>DONT OVERLAP ME</td><td width=100%>some other content</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2>
        <div style="width:100%; overflow-x:auto;">
CONTENT_WITH_ARBITRARY_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT_THE_TABLE_CELL_SHOULD_DISPLAY_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBARS_BUT_SHOULD_GROW_VERTICALLY_NORMALLY
        </div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>DONT OVERLAP ME</td><td width=100%>some other content</td></tr>
    </table>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
```

Here the overlapping is fixed, but for some reason the inner table just ignores that it is inside the other table and grows beyond the screen-edge and never displays the scrollbar. (I suspect this is again a symptom of "table-layout:fixed")

Is there a way to avoid overlapping and still have a table cell with an horizontal scroll-bar?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div style="max-width:100%; overflow-x:scroll;">
```

CONTENT_WITH_ARBITRARY_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT_THE_TABLE_CELL_SHOULD_DISPLAY_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBARS_BUT_SHOULD_GROW_VERTICALLY_NORMALLY

Note that you have width=100% in your code, make it max-width then a colon then 100%

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the mistake in the question but it did not have any inpact on the problem. Also "max-width" does not solve it.

Comment: I'm still trying, tried flex box ,border box  word wraps and all sorts. think there's a bit of a problem with this one...